# Bootstrap modal displays only on second call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

When I call the function for the first time nothing happens but on second click it works fine. On subsequent click result of the previous click is displayed. Below is my code

```
 <table class="table">

        <thead>
        <tr class="text-center" style="font-weight: bold">
            <td></td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>Registered On</td>
            <td>View Prescription</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in patientList | filter:filter_patient_list" class="text-center">
            <td>{{x.list}}</td>
            <td>{{x.name}}</td>
            <td>{{x.patient_id}}</td>
            <td>{{x.age}}</td>
            <td>{{x.date_registered}}</td>
            <td><button data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#view_prescription_from_patient_list{{x.patient_id}}" ng-click="getPrescriptionModal(x.patient_id)">/button></td>

        </tr>

    </table>
```

below is my angularJs code

```
$scope.getPrescriptionModal = function(patient_id)
{

    $http.get("ajax_get_data.php?get_what=prescription_list_for_patient_list&patient_id="+patient_id).success(function(response2)
    {
        $('#view_prescription_from_patient_list'+patient_id).modal('show');
        $('.modal_show').append(response2);

    }).error(function()
    {
        alert("Unable to fetch");
    })

}
```

and my php code to get modal window

```
    if($get_what == "prescription_list_for_patient_list")
{

    $patient_id = $_GET['patient_id'];
echo"
<div class='modal fade' id='view_prescription_from_patient_list$patient_id' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel'>
  <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-body'>
        ...
      </div>
      <div class='modal-footer'>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
";
```

I tried calling Ajax with Jquery that too had the same Issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to open a modal before it exists in the DOM.

Try appending the response to `<body>` first so that the selector you use to search for it will exist.

If the ID you are using is still only in the response html, using `$('#id')` searches for existing DOM elements and therefore won't find it

```
$http.get(url, function(response){
    $('body').append(response);
    $(selector).modal();
});
```

Alternatively you could also try;

```
$(response).modal();
```

I'm not sure if bootstrap will automatically append the response to the DOM or not doing it this way.

ALso strongly suggest getting rid of bootstrap.js and using angular-ui-bootstrap directive.

Comment: I tried appending to body and using angular-ui-bootstrap directive still the same error

Comment: is there any way I can load modal on body load and get the details of particular item as I click?

Comment: not sure what you mean...personally I would lean towards using one modal and changing it's content